# Is it possible to get the signature of a function in a shared library programmatically?

Tags: c, shared-libraries

The title is clear, we can loaded a library by `dl_open` etc..

But how can I get the signature of functions in it?

Comment: You might find the Wikipedia article on name mangling informative, to see the information encoded in object code names for C vs. C++ and how it varies by compiler: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: @Hostile Fork ,in a **single** `.so`,is it possible to have different name manglings?

Comment: As noted in the Wikipedia article, the name mangling in C is only to support Windows conventions and would not appear in `.so` files.  For C++ yes, different manglings of the same function name appear in one `.so` to support the language feature of overloading.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading

Comment: Given, that the number of popular languages has largely increased in the past 2 decades, would it not be fair to say, that adding some introspective meta data to elf files would help everyone? ELF is used not only by C/C++ and it would be a good step in the right direction to enhance binaries with information, allowing linking to e.g. shared libraries, no matter the language they were written in.

Answer (score 11):

This answer cannot be answered in general. Technically if you compiled your executable with exhaustive debugging information (code may still be an optimized, release version), then the executable will contain extra sections, providing some kind of reflectivity of the binary. On *nix systems (you referred to `dl_open`) this is implemented through [DWARF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DWARF) debugging data in extra sections of the [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) binary. Similar it works for *Mach Universal Binaries* on MacOS X.

Windows PEs however uses a completely different format, so unfortunately DWARF is not truley cross plattform (actually in the early development stages of my 3D engine I implemented an ELF/DWARF loader for Windows, so that I could use a common format for the engines various modules, so with some serious effort such can be done).

If you don't want to go into implementing your own loaders, or debugging information accessors, then you may embed the reflection information through some extra symbols exported (by some standard naming scheme) which refer to a table of function names, mapping to their signature. In the case of C source files writing a parser to extract the information from the source file itself is rather trivial. C++ OTOH is so notoriously difficult to parse correctly, that you need some fully fledged compiler to get it right. For this purpose GCCXML was developed, technically a GCC that emits the AST in XML form instead of an object binary. The emitted XML then is much easier to parse.

From the extracted information create a source file with some kind of linked list/array/etc. structure describing each function. If you don't directly export each function's symbol but instead initialize some field in the reflection structure with the function pointer you got a really nice and clean annotated exporting scheme. Technically you could place this information in a spearate section of the binary as well, but putting it in the read only data section does the job as well, too.

---

However if you're given a 3rd party binary – say worst case scenario it has been compiled from C source, no debugging information and all symbols not externally referenced stripped – you're pretty much screwed. The best you could do, was applying some binary analysis of the way the function accesses the various places in which parameters can be passed.

This will only tell you the number of parameters and the size of each parameter value, but not the type or name/meaning. When reverse engineering some program (e.g. malware analysis or security audit), identifying the type and meaning of the parameters passed to functions is one of the major efforts. Recently I came across some driver I had to reverse for debugging purposes, and you cannot believe how astounded I was by the fact that I found C++ symbols in a Linux kernel module (you can't use C++ in the Linux kernel in a sane way), but also relieved, because the C++ name mangling provided me with plenty information.

Answer (score 7):

On Linux (or Mac) you can use a combination of "nm" and "c++filt" (for C++ libraries)

> nm mylibrary.so | c++filt

or

> nm mylibrary.a | c++filt

"nm" will give you the mangled form and "c++filt" attempts to put them in a more human-readable format.  You might want to use some options in nm to filter down the results, especially if the library is large (or you can "grep" the final output to find a particular item)

Comment: On my Mac I had to do `nm -D -Ca mylibrary.so | c++filt`

Answer (score 4):

No this is not possible. Signature of a function doesn't mean anything at runtime, its a piece of information useful at compile time for the compiler to validate your program.

Comment: I don't think this statement is accurate, you're basically just categorically saying it's not possible. There's a lot of stuff that can be done to recover a signature; you can look at the calling convention, and if you can use taint analysis, you can track arguments from other known signatures and return types back to the desired function.

Answer (score 1):

You can't.  Either the library publishes a public API in a header, or you need to know the signature by some other means.

Answer (score 0):

The parameters of a function in the lower level depends on how many stack arguments in the stack frame you consider and how you interpret them. Therefore once the function is compiled into object code it is not possible to get the signature like that. One remote possibility is to disassemble the code and read how it function is working to know the number if parameters, but still the type would be difficult or impossible to determine. In a word, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This information is not available. Not even the debugger knows:

```
$ cat foo.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char foo[10] = { 0 };
    char bar[10] = { 0 };
    printf("%s\n", "foo");
    memcpy(bar, foo, sizeof(foo));
    return 0;
}

$ gcc -g -o foo foo.c
$ gdb foo
Reading symbols from foo...done.
(gdb) b main
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4005f3: file foo.c, line 5.
(gdb) r
Starting program: foo 

Breakpoint 1, main (argc=1, argv=0x7fffffffe3e8) at foo.c:5
5   {
(gdb) ptype printf
type = int ()
(gdb) ptype memcpy
type = int ()
(gdb)
```

Comment: At least the debugger knows it's a function, `int ()`.

Comment: @Je Rog, but as you can see for `memcpy` it just applies the default rules for the return type, so even that is not very helpful.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt ,do you know how debugger knows it's a function in the first place?

Comment: @Je Rog, probably depends a lot on the system, but usually the symbol table of an object file classifies the symbols into different categories. On Linux e.g you can inspect these with the `nm` utility.

Comment: @Je Rog, there are two ways you can tell by looking at the symbol table. One is by checking the flags, the second is checking the section name. Functions will be in the `.text` segment if they are defined within that binary, and will have the `F` flag to indicate that they are functions as opposed to something else. (`l` for local, `g` for global, etc - see `man objdump`)

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. I presented a concrete example of *why* it's not possible. All the other answers are just conjecture.